# Is it legal to incorporate replacement parts for another product into a new product?

Tags: hardware

In particular, I wonder about the use of mobile phone camera modules. Due to demand, price for replacement camera modules for mobile phones is very low.

Is it legal in the US to purchase such replacement parts and use them for a new, completely unrelated product?

Comment: Does this unrelated product already exist, or is it something you're creating? Because if it does, then the most I can think of is that its warranty would probably be voided. If you're creating something new with it, especially with the intent of commercialising it, then there may be some licencing issues.

Comment: It's something we're working on. We're adding a small camera - but all quotes we got so far for camera modules that would serve our needs have a unit price that is a multiple of some of the camera modules that are sold specifically as replacement parts for certain mobile phones (from third party vendors however).